# How to comment on image in colorbox (modal form)?

Tags: views, comments, javascript

I have created view to display images and also user to display it in popup using Colorbox trigger in view.

I want to allow users to comment on each individual image in modal form only. Just like Facebook. I have printed the comment form on popup but it is coming with preview button which redirects user to the photo's node page. And allow there to POST comment which I don't want.

What I want is user should be able to comment in popup with post button and the comment should be posted in modal form only (Should be visible in modal and node page as well). Is there any module to workout this?

Answer (score 0):

[Inline Ajax Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_comments) should do the trick for you.

> Inline Ajax Comments is a views handler that allows you to add a field
>   to a view to allow users to view and post comments on nodes in a view.
>   This is a basic version of what you see with commenting in social
>   networking sites like Facebook.

[Ajax Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) comments can also be considered.

Comment: Ajax Comments module is not working with me, When I include Ajax Add Comment Link to Colorbox trigger the link doesn't get appear in modal.

Comment: Is there anybody who knows the solutions?